# TypeError: Image data of dtype object cannot be converted to float as cv2 is not reading any image but the path is right

Tags: opencv, filepath, image-loading

I am trying to load an image in Python Jupyter notebook but I am getting an error as it is showing they are not getting any image.

```
img = cv2.imread(r"C:\Users\DELL\Desktop\download.jpg")
plt.imshow(img)
```

```
    The output I am getting is :
    
    TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
    <ipython-input-24-639b020df6f2> in <module>()
          1 img = cv2.imread(r"C:\Users\DELL\Desktop\download.jpg")
    ----> 2 plt.imshow(img)
    
    5 frames
    /usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/matplotlib/image.py in set_data(self, A)
        692                 not np.can_cast(self._A.dtype, float, "same_kind")):
        693             raise TypeError("Image data of dtype {} cannot be converted to "
    --> 694                             "float".format(self._A.dtype))
        695 
        696         if not (self._A.ndim == 2
    
    TypeError: Image data of dtype object cannot be converted to float
```

Comment: i have changed code according to this article but still not working

Comment: Yeah the path is correct

Comment: Added extra parameter cv2.imread(r"C:\Users\DELL\Desktop\download.jpg", 0)